# validaton for description field length if field contains first few characters after that few empty lines and again data

Tags: javascript

I need to validate on description field data, the field contains following content.

"URL:  http://192.168.0.214/SutiHR5.6

Thanks & Regards,
Srinivas T
Infobrain Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
Associate Software Engineer- IJ, SutiProcure, SutiHR
Tel: 91-40-66572424/25/26, Ext: # 101
Mobile: +91-9985276087
Web: www.infobraintech.com"

The above data I need to validate. How is it possible.
But descriptin column should not exceed 250 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Call the following function with passing the given `id` and `250`.

```
function validateLength(id, max) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value.length <= max;
}
```

`getElementById` returns the element which has the `id` passed as parameter. `value` is a string and has a `length` field, which represents the `length` of the string.

Comment: length method in javascript considers empty lines in the content?

Comment: length is not a method. It is a property. A string's length is the number of characters in the string, including newlines.